# Efficient way to create a list of specific values from a bunch of maps

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a List of maps

```
List<Map<String, Double>> maps = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap();
map1.put("height",60D);
map1.put("weight",144D);

maps.add(map1);


Map<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap();
map2.put("height",63D);
map2.put("weight",192D);

maps.add(map2);
```

and so on...

What's the quickest way to create a list of heights or weights?
Something like List heights etc.

The classic way is to look through the map, use an if condition and search for a height key and then if found, add it to a return list.

What would the equivalent way to do it using streams?

Comment: and it shouldn't compile, you have a `List<HashMap<String, Double>>`, but adding `Map<String, Double>`s

Answer (score 7):

```
List<Double> listHeights = maps.stream()
                                .map(map -> map.get("height"))
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Similarly, you can do it for `weight` also.

Comment: would add `null` to the resulting list if the map doesn't contain the key

Answer (score 2):

You could stream over the list and map the Maps to the relevant values:

```
List<Double> heights =
    maps.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.containsKey("height"))
        .map(m -> m.get("height"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: few missing closing brackets `)` around the `filter` and `map`... and `containsKey` would be a better alternative in the `filter`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get both `height` and `weight` list in one shot, then use `Collectors.groupingBy` no need of `contains` or `null` check

```
Map<String, List<Double>> result = maps.stream()
                                           .flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                   Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    result.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"..."+v));
```

**Output**

```
weight...[144.0, 192.0]
height...[60.0, 63.0]
```

And also you can use `getOrDefault` to get the `List` of height or weight

```
List<Double> height = result.getOrDefault("height", new ArrayList<Double>());
```